# How does it work and compile a C++ extension of TCL with a Macro and no main function

Tags: c++, macros, tcl

I have a working set of TCL script plus C++ extension but I dont know exactly how it works and how was it compiled. I am using gcc and linux Arch.

It works as follows: when we execute the test.tcl script it will pass some values to an object of a class defined into the C++ extension. Using these values the extension using a macro give some result and print some graphics.

In the test.tcl scrip I have:

```
#!object

use_namespace myClass 

proc simulate {} { 
    uplevel #0 {
      set running 1
         for {} {$running} { } {
        moveBugs
        draw .world.canvas
        .statusbar configure -text "t:[tstep]"
     }
    }
}

set toroidal 1
set nx 100
set ny 100
set mv_dist 4
setup $nx $ny $mv_dist $toroidal

addBugs 100

# size of a grid cell in pixels
set scale 5
myClass.scale 5
```

The object.cc looks like:

```
#include //some includes here

MyClass myClass;
make_model(myClass); // --> this is a macro!
```

The Macro "make_model(myClass)" expands as follows:

```
     namespace myClass_ns { DEFINE_MYLIB_LIBRARY; int TCL_obj_myClass
(mylib::TCL_obj_init(myClass),TCL_obj(mylib::null_TCL_obj,
(std::string)"myClass",myClass),1); };
```

The Class definition is:

```
class MyClass:
{
public:
  int tstep;   //timestep - updated each time moveBugs is called
  int scale;   //no. pixels used to represent bugs
  void setup(TCL_args args) {
    int nx=args, ny=args, moveDistance=args;
    bool toroidal=args;
    Space::setup(nx,ny,moveDistance,toroidal);
  }
```

The whole thing creates a cell-grid with some dots (bugs) moving from one cell to another.

My questions are:

- How do the class methods and variables get the script values?
- How is possible to have c++ code and compile it without a main function?
- What is that macro doing there in the extension and how it works??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a command in Tcl is run, it calls a function that implements that command. That function is written in a language like C or C++, and it is passed in the arguments (either as strings or `Tcl_Obj*` values). A full extension will also include a function to do the library initialisation; the function (which is external, has C linkage, and which has a name like `Foo_Init` if your library is `foo.dll`) does basic setting up tasks like registering the implementation functions as commands, and it's explicit because it takes a reference to the interpreter context that is being initialised.

The implementation functions can do pretty much anything they want, but to return a result they use one of the functions `Tcl_SetResult`, `Tcl_SetObjResult`, etc. and they have to return an `int` containing the relevant exception code. The usual useful ones are `TCL_OK` (for no exception) and `TCL_ERROR` (for stuff's gone wrong). This is a C API, so C++ exceptions aren't allowed.

It's possible to use C++ instance methods as command implementations, provided there's a binding function in between. In particular, the function has to get the instance pointer by casting a `ClientData` value (an alias for `void*` in reality, remember this is *mostly* a C API) and then invoking the method on that. It's a small amount of code.

---

Compiling things is just building a DLL that links against the right library (or libraries, as required). While extensions are usually recommended to link against the stub library, it's not necessary when you're just developing and testing on one machine. But if you're linking against the Tcl DLL, you'd better make sure that the code gets loaded into a tclsh that uses that DLL. Stub libraries get rid of that tight binding, providing pretty strong ABI stability, but are little more work to set up; you need to define the right C macro to turn them on and you need to do an extra API call in your initialisation function.

I assume you already know how to compile and link C++ code. I won't tell you how to do it, but there's bound to be other questions here on Stack Overflow if you need assistance.

Using the code? For an extension, it's basically just:

```
# Dynamically load the DLL and call the init function
load /path/to/your.dll

# Commands are all present, so use them
NewCommand 3
```

There are some extra steps later on to turn a DLL into a proper Tcl package, abstracting code that uses the DLL away from the fact that it is exactly that DLL and so on, but they're not something to worry about until you've got things working a lot more.

Comment: @JoselitoS Your sample is really hard to understand, as it is missing very many details. Edit your question to put the info in there. (The comments here are very limited in how much you can write; they're for _comments_ and not full discussions.)

Comment: Yes! but your answer relly helped me. I am working on it and I will improve the question in a few days for it to be useful for everyone

Comment: I reformulated the question, i hope it can be better understood now